# How to open a large sql script (22GB!) in ubuntu?

Tags: file, ubuntu

I have a sql script which makes tables and adds data but the file is very huge, 22GB!! I'm unable to open it in gedit/vim with LargeFile/chrome. Nothing seems to be working.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/28847/text-editor-to-edit-4-3-gb-plain-text-file):

> Another method is to use split. Split the file into `n` pieces and
>   manipulate the files with a editor. After that, you reassemble the
>   files again.
>
> ```
> split -b <size of a part> <your-file>
>
> cat xa* > <your-file>
>
>
> SYNOPSIS
>    split [OPTION]... [INPUT [PREFIX]]
>
>    -a, --suffix-length=N
>           use suffixes of length N (default 2)
>
>    -b, --bytes=SIZE
>           put SIZE bytes per output file
>
>    -C, --line-bytes=SIZE
>           put at most SIZE bytes of lines per output file
>
>    -d, --numeric-suffixes
>           use numeric suffixes instead of alphabetic
>
>    -l, --lines=NUMBER
>           put NUMBER lines per output file
> ```

Comment: Thank you. This worked. I'm now able to view the file in parts.